# JQuery Button Firing Twice

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm try to get the specific data of the table row whenever I click the Edit Button that's on the same row as the data I'm trying to get i get double output, it seems like my edit button is firing twice since I'm getting a double output in my console.
 [double output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44g9x.png) I'm new just here, so please guide me through. I cant see why my button is firing twice, but when I add **$("body").off();** the problem is gone.

can you guys help me why my edit button is firing twice?

edit:
I removed this code and still firing twice

```
 <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-action" data-action = "delete" data-client-id = "<?= $item['customer_id'] ?>" name="delete"> Delete</button></td>
```

customerlist.php

```
<!-- table code goes here -->
<div class="container mt-5">
    <table class="table table-hover">
    <h2>CUSTOMER LIST</h2>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Count</th>
            <th scope="col">Firstname</th>
            <th scope="col">Lastname</th>
            <th scope="col">Email Address</th>
            <th scope="col">Address</th>
            <th scope="col">Username</th>
            <th scope="col">Contract Started</th>
            <th scope="col">Contract Ended</th>
            <th scope="col">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <!-- checking DB connection and accessing data-->
    <?php
    include("classlib/query.inc.php");

    //checking if Database is Connected
    $object = new Dbh;
    $object->connect();
    //end of checking

    //getting the table data
    $tableData = new Query();
    $count=1;

    foreach($tableData->selectAll('customer_info') as $item){

    // var_dump($item);

  ?>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $count ?></th>
            <td><?= $item['first_name'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $item['last_name'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $item['email_address'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $item['home_address'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $item['username'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $item['contract_start'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $item['contract_end'] ?></td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-action" data-action = "edit" data-client-id = "<?= $item['customer_id'] ?>" name="edit"> Edit</button></td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>

    <?php
        $count++;
        } //end tag of foreach loop
    ?>

    </table>
<!-- end of table code -->
```

core.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //some add data codes here

    //edit and delete
    // $("body").off();
    $('body').on('click', '.btn-action', function(){
        var action = $(this).data('action');
        var customerID = $(this).data('client-id');

        if (action == "edit"){
            $.ajax({
                url: "php/client_action.php",
                type: "post",
                data: {action:action,customerID:customerID},
                success: function(data){
                    $("#myModal").modal();
                    x = JSON.parse(data);
                    // console.log(data);
                    console.log(x);
                }
            });

        }
    });

});
```

query.inc.php

```
<?php
include("connection.inc.php");

class Query extends Dbh {

    /**
     * returning all value from specific table
     */

    public function selectAll($table){
        try{
            $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table");
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

            /**
             * returning the value of the table
             */
            foreach($result as $item){
                $data[]=$item;
            };
            return $data;

        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage(); 
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function selectId($table, $id){
        try{
            $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE customer_id=:customerID");
            $stmt->execute([
                'customerID' => $id
            ]);

            $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            /**
             * returning the value of the table
             */
            // foreach($result as $item){
            //  $data[]=$item;
            // };

            // return $result;

            // var_dump($result);
            echo json_encode($result);
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage(); 
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

client_action.php

```
<?php
include("../classlib/query.inc.php");

if($_POST["action"] == "edit"){
    $showIdInfo =  new Query();
    $result = $showIdInfo->selectId('customer_info', $_POST['customerID']);
    // echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Comment: Can you remove the codes that are not necessary? You said the problem is within a jQuery code, so we don't really need to see the codes to your connection, etc.

Comment: My guess is that the "on-event" is triggered twice, hence you have two on-event triggers for the button-click. Are your core.js -file included multiple times in your code somewhere or by any other files?

Comment: you have to disable the button when you submit the form..This will save you. @kairi

Comment: @Swellar already removed

Comment: @Araw I removed the delete button, but still firing twice, I updated my post

Comment: @lalithkumar what do you mean?

Comment: which means onclick on the `btn-action` make it disable this  @kairi

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you did not assign any "type" to buttons so its triggering 2 times please try and tell me.

```
<td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-action" data-action = "edit" data-client-id = "<?= $item['customer_id'] ?>" name="edit"> Edit</button></td>
<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-action" data-action = "delete" data-client-id = "<?= $item['customer_id'] ?>" name="delete"> Delete</button></td>
```

Comment: Already did, but still the same. But I removed the Delete button, still firing twice.

Comment: One more thing to check is js script is getting load only once

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one in your core.js;

```
$('.btn-action').unbind().click(function () {
    // your actions
});
```